# how to trace restart of MySQL container?

Tags: mysql, kubernetes

I have mysql running in k8s with one replicaset, it keeps crashing at random times with exit code 137. Memory consumption is 82% while crashing.

I couldn't find anything in syslog, mysql error log and kubelet log other than restart message.

Instance is already having 64gb and once after the restart it is able to handle the application requests. So increasing memory should not be an actual solution.

Also monitoring tools says only 82% of the memory is being used at the time of crash.

1. How kubernetes calculates the memory consumption of a pod?
2. How to find why it is crashing?

Comment: database application is stateful

Comment: i understand statefulset gives few features for stateful apps.. but is there any advantage of statefulset on performance basis?

Comment: Our company's approach is to mount the database deployment data directory to NFS with PVC.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `kubectl logs your-pod -c container-name -n your-namespaces` to see your log, use `kubectl describe pod your-pod -n your-namespaces` to see pod events.

Comment: i see only MySQL error logs in that, nothing related to container restart

Comment: do you try to increase limits memory? 137 is oom flag.

Comment: modified my question